# For finite Galois extensions $K \leq L$, when is $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ and $K$-basis for $L$?

Tags: galois-theory

I am given that $K \leq L$ is a Galois extension and that the Galois group is $G= \{\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n\}$ and asked to prove that:

$$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} \text{ is a }K \text{-basis iff } \det\sigma_i(\alpha_j) \neq 0 $$

I am assuming that $\sigma_i(\alpha_j)$ is the matrix defined entrywise as $A_{ij} = \sigma_i(\alpha_j)$

I want to say something along the lines of:

$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ is a $K$-basis for $L \Rightarrow \{\sigma_k(\alpha_1), \dots, \sigma_k(\alpha_n)\}$ is a $K$-basis for $L$ for all $k$
$\Rightarrow A$ has full column rank and so $\det A \neq 0 $

and:

If for some $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ we have $\det A \neq 0$, then $ A$ invertible and so $A$ has full column rank $\Rightarrow \{\sigma_k(\alpha_1), \dots, \sigma_k(\alpha_n)\}$ is a $K$-basis for $L$ for all $k$, and as the identity is in G, this means $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ must also be a $K$-basis for $L$

However, I am not too sure what the statement "$A$ has full rank" means in this context, or if I am even correct in attempting this approach. Could anyone give me some insight into what matrix $A$ actually represents and what "having full rank" would imply? Thank you.